# my expression fails with a runtime exception

Tags: mule, mule-el

I'm attempting to bring back one of the element values from an IDOC, to determine a variable value. When I run this in the debugger just to test it brings back the right value, but when i run it as part of the expression it fails -

```
import java.lang.String;

String destination = #[xpath3('*/IDOC/EDI_DC40/RCVPRN',payload,'STRING')];
    if(destination.equals('EUMULESOFT')) {
        flowVars.vDestination = "EuropeanDC";
    }
    else {
        flowVars.vDestination = "WestwayDC";
    }
```

Is it the MEL expression itself? I was wondering whether perhaps i needed payload.xpath3 instead?

Comment: what it means "fails" ? do you see an error?

Comment: Ah sorry i missed this bit off - fails with a runtime exception error.

Comment: could you post it?

Comment: Also add the input, to understand the expected result.